# SSRS Initialization Issues

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I was wondering what the impact on SSRS Initialization would be if the SQL Server instance hosting the Reporting Server database was taken offline.

To provide more detail, the database instance is a disaster recovery (DR) instance and must remain offline to facilitate data replication from the live database.

At the moment the DR SSRS is not initialized but it was prior to taking the DR SQL Server instance offline.  It is also has identical configuration to the live SSRS which is initialized.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would expect the SSRS service would continue to run, but the Report Manager website (or SharePoint SSRS content), web service etc would not be available.